# Is there a way to refuse Process Hooking on JailBreak IOS devices

Tags: reverse-engineering

I want to find a way to prevent apps from Cycript attaching. So Far I Know Cycript works as below, but I can not find a way to stop Cycript.

One method to stop injection is to add "-Wl,-sectcreate,__RESTRICT,__restrict,/dev/null", but it is very easy to be bypassed.

Any other suggestion to stop Cycript?

Cycript uses cynject in mobile substrate
https://git.saurik.com/cycript.git/blob/HEAD:/Inject.cpp

Cynject uses the mach task port to inject and create a thread in the target process:
https://github.com/rweichler/substrate/blob/master/DarwinInjector.cpp

```
mach_port_t self(mach_task_self()), task;
_krncall(task_for_pid(self, pid, &task));
```